# Sending message in Laravel

Tags: php, message, store, laravel-6

I got a form that uses

```
Session::flush('status','post has added');
return redirect('/form');
```

to store data and send a message.

The form route is:

```
Route::get('/form',function (){return view('form');})->name('form')->middleware('auth');
```

The problem is that when a user adds a post they will be logged out and routed to the login form. But I wanted to return to the same form where the message has been passed in.

Answer (score -1):

You are adding the Auth Middleware. Remove it and try again.

Comment: No,user should be authenticated to access this form.